# JavaFX: Pathfinding using Point2D and Line

Tags: java, math, javafx, path-finding

I need to implement sort of a pathfinding algorithm, the context is the following:
I have a starting Point2D, and and objective (a Circle).
I draw a line between the starting point and the circle center.
I try to calculate a path that does not cross any other circles.
(The blue square is my object I want to move (at starting point)) and the red circle is my objective).
[image: Multiples circle with a line intersecting one of them]
What I wanted to do first was to do something like this:[image: Image showing a path avoiding the circle]
But the code I have seems to be buggy as sometimes, I've got negatives intersection coordonates (black points).
Is there any other way to solve this problem ? Am I seeing the problem from a correct point of view ? There is also a problem as I'm iterating over the circles to determines which intersects or not, but if the line intersect 2 or more circles, the order of which it intersect planets is different from the order I see the points on screen.
My goal is to create a PathTransition between starting point and objective following the correct path (no intersection).

I've not mentioned it, but the container is a Pane.

EDIT:

```
public static Point2D getMidPoint(Point2D p1, Point2D p2) {
    return new Point2D((p1.getX() + p2.getX()) / 2, (p1.getY() + p2.getY()) / 2);
}

public static Circle createCircleFromPoint2D(Point2D p) {
    return new Circle(p.getX(), p.getY(), 5);
}

public static Point2D createPoint2D(double x, double y) {
    return new Point2D(x, y);
}

public static Pair<Point2D, Point2D> translate(int distance, Point2D p1, Point2D p2, double reference, double startX) {
    double pente = (p2.getY() - p1.getY()) / (p2.getX() - p1.getX());
    double newX1 = p1.getX() + (startX < reference ? -1 : 1) * (Math.sqrt(((distance*distance) / (1 + (pente*pente)))));
    double newX2 = p2.getX() + (startX > reference ? -1 : 1) * (Math.sqrt(((distance*distance) / (1 + (pente*pente)))));
    double newY1 = pente * (newX1 - p1.getX()) + p1.getY();
    double newY2 = pente * (newX2 - p2.getX()) + p2.getY();

    return new Pair<>(new Point2D(newX1, newY1), new Point2D(newX2, newY2));
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Pane pane = new Pane();

    Circle objective = new Circle(800, 250, 25);
    Circle circle2 = new Circle(500, 250, 125);
    Circle circle3 = new Circle(240, 400, 75);
    Circle circle4 = new Circle(700, 500, 150, Color.VIOLET);
    Circle circle5 = new Circle(1150, 300, 115, Color.ORANGE);

    Rectangle myObject = new Rectangle(175, 175, 15, 15);

    objective.setFill(Color.RED);
    circle2.setFill(Color.BLUE);
    circle3.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    myObject.setFill(Color.BLUE);

    ArrayList<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<>();
    circles.add(objective);
    circles.add(circle2);
    circles.add(circle3);
    circles.add(circle4);
    circles.add(circle5);

    Line straightLine = new Line();
    pane.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            myObject.setX(event.getX());
            myObject.setY(event.getY());

            // My starting coordinates (at mouse position)
            double fromX = myObject.getX();
            double fromY = myObject.getY();

            // Where I want to go
            double toX = objective.getCenterX();
            double toY = objective.getCenterY();

            // Line style
            straightLine.setStartX(event.getX());
            straightLine.setStartY(event.getY());
            straightLine.setEndX(toX);
            straightLine.setEndY(toY);
            straightLine.setStrokeWidth(2);
            straightLine.setStroke(Color.GRAY.deriveColor(0, 1, 1, 0.5));
            straightLine.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.BUTT);
            straightLine.getStrokeDashArray().setAll(10.0, 5.0);
            straightLine.setMouseTransparent(true);

            // Coordinates to Point2D
            Point2D from = new Point2D(fromX, fromY);
            Point2D to = new Point2D(toX, toY);

            Path path = new Path();
            path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(fromX, fromY));

            for (Circle c : circles) {
                if (straightLine.intersects(c.getLayoutBounds())) {

                    // I don't want to do anything if I'm intersecting the objective (for now)
                    if (c == objective)
                        continue;

                    Shape s = Shape.intersect(straightLine, c);

                    double xmin = s.getBoundsInLocal().getMinX();
                    double ymin = s.getBoundsInLocal().getMinY();
                    double xmax = s.getBoundsInLocal().getMaxX();
                    double ymax = s.getBoundsInLocal().getMaxY();

                    Point2D intersectionPt1 = createPoint2D((fromX < objective.getCenterX()) ? xmin : xmax , (fromY < objective.getCenterY()) ? ymin : ymax);
                    Point2D intersectionPt2 = createPoint2D((fromX > objective.getCenterX()) ? xmin : xmax , (fromY < objective.getCenterY()) ? ymax : ymin);

                    Point2D middlePt = getMidPoint(intersectionPt1, intersectionPt2);
                    Circle circlePt1 = new Circle(intersectionPt1.getX(), intersectionPt1.getY(), 5);
                    Circle circlePt2 = new Circle(intersectionPt2.getX(), intersectionPt2.getY(), 5);
                    Circle circleMiddle = new Circle(middlePt.getX(), middlePt.getY(), 5, Color.RED);

                    if (c != objective) {
                        // To calculate the points just before/after the first/second points (green points)
                        Pair<Point2D, Point2D> pts = translate(50, intersectionPt1, intersectionPt2, objective.getCenterX(), fromX);
                        Point2D beforePt1 = pts.getKey();
                        Point2D beforePt2 = pts.getValue();
                        Circle circleBeforePt1 = createCircleFromPoint2D(beforePt1);
                        Circle circleBeforePt2 = createCircleFromPoint2D(beforePt2);
                        circleBeforePt1.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                        circleBeforePt2.setFill(Color.GREEN);

                        pane.getChildren().addAll(circleBeforePt1, circleBeforePt2);
                    }

                    pane.getChildren().addAll(s, circlePt1, circlePt2, circleMiddle);
                }
            }

            PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
            pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
            pathTransition.setNode(myObject);
            pathTransition.setPath(path);
            pathTransition.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);

            pathTransition.play();
        }
    });

    pane.getChildren().addAll(circles);
    pane.getChildren().addAll(myObject, straightLine);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 1600, 900);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

I want to calculate a path (not necessarily a shortest path) from Point A to Point B, but can't figure it out how. Now I have the points where I would like to pass, I don't know how to link them togethers.

Comment: Where’s the question and where’s the code? Kinda a hard to help without them. Please review [ask].

Comment: The second picture does not actually show the shortest path. The shortest path would be 2 tangents to the circle and the circle section connecting the 2 intersections between tangent and circle (the circle can be aproximated using infinitely many line segments).

Comment: It doesn't have to be necessarily the shortest path, just a path that avoid any collision between Point A and Point B.

Comment: @rlasvenes, should the path be constructed of line segments? Probably The simplest path is to go along the line and the avoid the circle by going through the arc on its edge.

Comment: One thing I've wanted to do is to create an arc joining the 2 green points in the picture, but I don't know how. It would be cool if its not constructed of segments, but nevermind if it is.

Comment: You need to provide a complete working example . In the code your provided,. createPoint2D, getMidPoint, translate & createCircleFromPoint2D methods are missing.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution strategy and implementation

I built a solution with the following strategy: On a given line `from(X,Y)` to `to(X,Y)` I compute the closest intersection with one of the obstacle shapes. From that shape I take the length of the intersection as a measure of how large the obstacle is, and take a look at the points left and right by 1/2 of that length from some point shortly before the intersection. The first of the left and right points that is not inside an obstacle is then used to sub-divide the task of finding a path around the obstacles.

```
    protected void computeIntersections(double fromX, double fromY, double toX, double toY) {
        // recursively test for obstacles and try moving around them by 
        // calling this same procedure on the segments to and from 
        // a suitable new point away from the line
        Line testLine = new Line(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
        //compute the unit direction of the line
        double dX = toX-fromX, dY = toY-fromY;
        double ds = Math.hypot(dX,dY);
        dX /= ds; dY /= ds;
        
        // get the length from the initial point of the minimal intersection point
        // and the opposite point of the same obstacle, remember also the closest obstacle
        double t1=-1, t2=-1;
        Shape obst = null;
        
        for (Shape c : lstObstacles) {
            if (testLine.intersects(c.getLayoutBounds())) {
            
                Shape s = Shape.intersect(testLine, c);
                if( s.getLayoutBounds().isEmpty() ) continue;
                // intersection bounds of the current shape
                double s1, s2;
                if(Math.abs(dX) < Math.abs(dY) ) {
                    s1 = ( s.getBoundsInLocal().getMinY()-fromY ) / dY;
                    s2 = ( s.getBoundsInLocal().getMaxY()-fromY ) / dY;
                } else {
                    s1 = ( s.getBoundsInLocal().getMinX()-fromX ) / dX;
                    s2 = ( s.getBoundsInLocal().getMaxX()-fromX ) / dX;
                }
                // ensure s1 < s2
                if ( s2 < s1 ) { double h=s2; s2=s1; s1=h; }
                // remember the closest intersection
                if ( ( t1 < 0 ) || ( s1 < t1 ) ) { t1 = s1; t2 = s2; obst = c; }
            }
        }
        // at least one intersection found
        if( ( obst != null ) && ( t1 > 0 )  ) {
            intersectionDecorations.getChildren().add(Shape.intersect(testLine, obst));
            // coordinates for the vertex point of the path
            double midX, midY; 
            // go to slightly before the intersection set
            double intersectX = fromX + 0.8*t1*dX, intersectY = fromY + 0.8*t1*dY;
            // orthogonal segment of half the length of the intersection, go left and right
            double perpX = 0.5*(t2-t1)*dY, perpY = 0.5*(t1-t2)*dX;
            Rectangle testRect = new Rectangle( 10, 10);
            // go away from the line to hopefully have less obstacle from the new point
            while( true ) {
                // go "left", test if free
                midX = intersectX + perpX; midY = intersectY + perpY;
                testRect.setX(midX-5); testRect.setY(midY-5); 
                if( Shape.intersect(testRect, obst).getLayoutBounds().isEmpty() ) break;
                // go "right"
                midX = intersectX - perpX; midY = intersectY - perpY;
                testRect.setX(midX-5); testRect.setY(midY-5); 
                if( Shape.intersect(testRect, obst).getLayoutBounds().isEmpty() ) break;
                // if obstacles left and right, try closer points next
                perpX *= 0.5; perpY *= 0.5;
            }
            intersectionDecorations.getChildren().add(new Line(intersectX, intersectY, midX, midY));
            // test the first segment for intersections with obstacles
            computeIntersections(fromX, fromY, midX, midY);
            // add the middle vertex to the solution path
            connectingPath.getElements().add(new LineTo(midX, midY));
            // test the second segment for intersections with obstacles
            computeIntersections(midX, midY, toX, toY);
        }
    }
```

This first chosen point might not be the most optimal one, as one can see, but it does the job. To do better one would have to construct some kind of decision tree of the left-right decisions and then chose the shortest path among the variants. All the usual strategies then apply, like starting a second tree from the target location, depth-first search etc.

[image: pathfinder application]

The auxillary lines are the intersections that were used and the perpendicular lines to the new midpoints.

### PathfinderApp.java

I used this problem to familiarize myself with the use of FXML, thus the main application has the usual boilerplate code.

```
package pathfinder;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PathfinderApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("pathfinder.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Finding a path around obstacles");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1600, 900));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

### pathfinder.fxml

The FXML file contains the "most" static (in the sense of always present for the given type of task) elements of the user interface. These are the cursor rectangle, the target circle and a line between them. Then groups for the obstacles and "decorations" from the path construction, and the path itself. This separation allows to clear and populate these groupings independent from each other with no other organizational effort.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.Group?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Line?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Path?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Circle?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.Color?> 

<Pane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" 
      fx:controller="pathfinder.PathfinderController" onMouseClicked="#setCursor">
    <Circle fx:id="target" centerX="800" centerY="250" radius="25" fill="red"/>
    <Rectangle fx:id="cursor" x="175" y="175" width="15" height="15" fill="lightblue"/>
    <Line fx:id="straightLine" startX="${cursor.X}" startY="${cursor.Y}" endX="${target.centerX}" endY="${target.centerY}" 
          strokeWidth="2" stroke="gray" strokeLineCap="butt" strokeDashArray="10.0, 5.0" mouseTransparent="true" />
    <Group fx:id="obstacles" />
    <Group fx:id="intersectionDecorations" />
    <Path fx:id="connectingPath" strokeWidth="2" stroke="blue" />
</Pane>
```

### PathfinderController.java

The main work is done in the controller. Some minimal initialization binding the target and cursor to their connecting line and the mouse event handler (with code that prevents the cursor to be placed inside some obstacle) and then the path finding procedures. One framing procedure and the recursive workhorse from above.

```
package pathfinder;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo; 
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo; 
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

import java.util.*;

public class PathfinderController {

    @FXML
    private Circle target;

    @FXML
    private Rectangle cursor;
    
    @FXML
    private Line straightLine;
    
    @FXML
    private Path connectingPath;
    
    @FXML
    private Group obstacles, intersectionDecorations;
    
    private static List<Shape> lstObstacles = Arrays.asList(
        new Circle( 500, 250, 125, Color.BLUE  ),  
        new Circle( 240, 400,  75, Color.GREEN ), 
        new Circle( 700, 500, 150, Color.VIOLET), 
        new Circle(1150, 300, 115, Color.ORANGE)
    );
    
    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        straightLine.startXProperty().bind(cursor.xProperty());
        straightLine.startYProperty().bind(cursor.yProperty());
        obstacles.getChildren().addAll(lstObstacles);
        findPath();
    }
    
    @FXML
    protected void setCursor(MouseEvent e) {
        Shape test = new Rectangle(e.getX()-5, e.getY()-5, 10, 10);
        for (Shape c : lstObstacles) {
            if( !Shape.intersect(c, test).getLayoutBounds().isEmpty() ) return;
        }
        
        cursor.setX(e.getX());
        cursor.setY(e.getY());        
        findPath();
    }
    
    protected void findPath() {
        double fromX = cursor.getX();
        double fromY = cursor.getY();
                
        double toX = target.getCenterX();
        double toY = target.getCenterY();
                
        intersectionDecorations.getChildren().clear();
        connectingPath.getElements().clear();
        
        // first point of path
        connectingPath.getElements().add(new MoveTo(fromX, fromY));
        // check path for intersections, move around if necessary
        computeIntersections(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
        // last point of the path
        connectingPath.getElements().add(new LineTo(toX, toY));
    }

    protected void computeIntersections(double fromX, double fromY, double toX, double toY) {
        ...
        }
    
    // end class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the desired answer, but did you think about unit testing your math code? It is easy to do for math code and then you can be sure the low level functions work correct.

If you still have the bug afterwards, you can write a unit test for easier reproducing it and post it here.

**On Topic:**

Your algorithm with the lines can get quite complex or even find no solution with more and/or overlapping circles.

Why not use the standard A* algorithm, where all non-white pixels are obstacles. Is that overkill?

Comment: I think this is instead of a comment to my answer? There is no bug, the program does exactly what it was programmed to do. And yes, something like A* would be the next step, perhaps using squares or circles in a hex-pattern. Obviously there will always be critical cases when the obstacles get to close, but for the given configuration that should work fine.

Comment: Yes, maybe it would be better as a comment, but I have not enough reputation to comment other people.

Squares would be easier, because than you could use  JavaFx for rendering and export it as image.